# JDK8 adjust time of a java.time.Instant

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to adjust the time of a `java.time.Instant`.

I tried this code:

```
Instant validFrom = //from my method parameter
validFrom = validFrom.with(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19).with(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY, 00)
                    .with(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 00).with(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY, 00);
```

But I've an exception:

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: HourOfDay
    at java.time.Instant.with(Instant.java:720)
```

This is quite expected reading the documentation and checking the source code.
It's not really clear to me why I can't do that. Is there another way to to this operation without incurring in many conversions?

Comment: With a bare `Instant`, how would it know what time zone to use?

Comment: @chrylis I'm working in UTC.

Comment: Just use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)? Instant does not have any notion of hours, nor does it know about timezones, it's simply an instant in time.

Comment: `Instant` has no concept of UTC.

Comment: As an aside, instead of setting minutes, seconds and smaller units, you can just use `.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)`.

Comment: A warning, don’t write literals with prefixed 0 in Java. This means an octal number. While 00 in octal also means 0, 011, for example means 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `Instant` has no timezone information. 19:00 hours doesn't represent anything useful, unless you attach a timezone to it.

You can convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` object, and then convert it back to an `Instant` like this:

```java
public void testInstant(){
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    ZonedDateTime utc = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = utc.withHour(19)
            .withMinute(0)
            .withSecond(0);

    Instant instant = zonedDateTime.toInstant();
}
```

Comment: I’d slightly prefer an `OffsetDateTime`, `now.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. Otherwise this answer shows the way to go.